# ¿Cómo referirme a un servidor en la red local en linux?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, linux

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un proyecto de express que utiliza el paquete [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) para conectarse a una base de datos de SQL Server. Para realizar la conexión tengo que especificar los datos en un objeto.

```
produccion = {
  user: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx',
  server: 'nombre\\nombre',
  database: 'xxx'
};
```

En el caso de `server` contiene un `\\`. Aunque realmente no sé por qué.

Estoy desarrollando el proyecto en la red local con una máquina con Windows, no tengo problema al conectarme al servidor. Ahora cuando lo paso a un servidor Debian que también está en la red local no se puede establecer la conexión.

He intentado sustituir el `nombre\\nombre` por la ip, pero no funciona ni en mi máquina de Windows ni en el servidor Debian.

Este es el error que me manda:

```
{ ConnectionError: Failed to lookup instance on miServidor - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND miServidor    at Connection.tedious.once.err (/var/www/html/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:239:17)    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)    at /var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:848:20    at /var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js:83:15    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (/var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js:58:18)    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:70:17)  code: 'EINSTLOOKUP',  originalError:   { ConnectionError: Failed to lookup instance on miServidor - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND miServidor       at ConnectionError (/var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:12:12)       at /var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:848:36       at /var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js:83:15       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (/var/www/html/node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js:58:18)       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:70:17)     message:      'Failed to lookup instance on miServidor - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND miServidor',
     code: 'EINSTLOOKUP' },
  name: 'ConnectionError' }
```

La documentación de `mssql` no es muy clara sobre el código `EINSTLOOKUP`.

```
EINSTLOOKUP (ConnectionError) - Instance lookup failed.
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te marca?

Comment: @dbamex Gracias. Edité la pregunta para incluir el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes sustituir `nombre\nombre` por una IP, ya que no son equivalentes. Voy a explicarte lo que el cliente de *SQL Server* soporta en ese parámetro de conexión y creo que después de eso podrás hacerlo tu solo.

Cuando te vas a conectar a una base de datos, hay un parámetro comunmente conocido como *nombre del servidor*, *server name* o simplemente *server*, que indica al motor el nombre calificado de **la instancia** de SQL Server a la que debe conectarse.

En otras palabras, no es **el equipo** al que se conecta, sino **la instancia**, que siempre va a residir dentro de un equipo y puede ser la única instancia o la instancia *default* (vamos a eso más adelante).

Comencemos por definir las *partes* a de las que eventualmente puede componerse:

- **host** es el equipo al que deseamos comunicarnos, puede ser

  - Un nombre de equipo en una red Windows (NetBios), por ejemplo `MiPC` o `Juan-Laptop`
  - Un nombre de host (local o remoto) en la estructura DNS, por ejemplo `midominio.com`, `basededatos.midominio.com`, etc.
  - Una IP accesible desde la red (privada o pública), tal como `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.0.41`, `190.191.192.193`, etc.
  - El nombre especial `(local)`, que siempre resuelve al propio equipo.
- **nombreInstancia** es el nombre que se le ha dado a la instancia dentro del *host* servidor de base de datos. Recuerda que un único equipo puede tener una o varias *instancias* del servidor de base de datos, cada uno con su propia configuración y corriendo incluso distintas versiones de *SQL Server*.
- **PuertoTCP** es el número del puerto *TCP* en el que una instancia particular ha sido configurado para *escuchar* por la red.

Ya con esto en mente, la cadena del *server name* puede tomar 3 formas:

1. **host\nombreInstancia**: ejemplos: `ServidorBD\SQLExpress`, `db.miempresa.com\MainERP`, `10.14.17.11\Pruebas`, etc.
2. **host,puertoTCP**: ejemplos: `ServidorBD,1433`, `db.miempresa.com,61254`, `10.14.17.11,18141`
3. **host** Se conecta a la instancia *default* (sin nombre) en un equipo, a través del puerto 1433, que es el estándar de SQL Server.

Esto es igual si el servidor es *Windows* o *Linux*.

Para diagnosticar el problema, lo que debes verificar, desde el equipo donde estás intentando establecer la conexión, es que:

- El nombre del servidor pueda resolverse sin problemas. Puedes probarlo fácilmente, por ejemplo, haciendo un `ping` con el nombre del servidor, aprovechando que este comando hace el *lookup* del nombre, lo traduce a una dirección IP y finalmente intenta hacer el *ping*. Una prueba en Windows, cuando no puede resolver el nombre, arroja algo como:

  ```
  C:\Users\juan>ping prueba
  La solicitud de ping no pudo encontrar el host prueba. Compruebe el nombre y
  vuelva a intentarlo.
  ```

  En linux es algo similar
- Que puedes conectarte al puerto del *SQL server*, ya sea con telnet, con algún cliente del SQL Server o con cualquier otro programa que pueda establecer una conexión TCP, por ejemplo.

  ```
  C:\Users\juan>telnet MiServidor 1433
  ```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, @jachguate ! Tenía que usar `la-ip-del-equipo\\el-nombre-de-la-instancia`