# Error de puertos tcp ip en conexion java con sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

bueno,mas que problema en el codigo creo que sera de instalacion pero bueno, si logran ayudarme se los agradeceria muchisimo:
Todo comienza cuando tengo que instalar sql server 2014 express edition en la computadora de un cliente,todo bien, hasta se puede crear base de datos, tambien abri el puerto 1433 en el firewall,tanto de entrada como de salida,pero al ejecutar el siguiente codigo de conexion para hacer una consulta en la base de datos el cual es el siguiente(java):

```
    package accesoDatos;

import java.sql.*;

public class conexion {
    public static Connection Conectar() throws Exception{
        try {

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ISPL\\ISPL:1433;"
                    + "databaseName=TecnoTrony","sa","sql");


            /*
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ORLANDO-PC:1433;"
                    + "databaseName=TecnoTrony","sa","sql");
            */  

            return cn;


        }catch (Exception e) {

            throw e;

        }

    }
}
```

Al depurarlo me devuleve el tipico error de que los puertos tcp ip estan cerrados o que no puede conectar por algun otro motivo,resalto que el jdk y version de java son las mismas,el .net algo que no me pude fijar supongo que sera el minimo requerido para sql server 2014,si no de otra manera no se hubiera instalado este mismo,lo unico que pude haber olvidado quizas sea definir el puerto tcp ip en el gerente de servicios de sql server, suponiendo que no,que es lo que puede que genere este error?

Comment: El error está en la cadena de conexión, por favor, lee [estarespuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/219192/21).

Comment: si lo dices por la parte que dice "sqlserver://ISPL\\ISPL:1433" ,los nombres estan bien puestos (la otra conexion de abajo esta comentada)

Comment: ¿Has intentado quitar el puerto de la cadena de conexión? ¿te puedes conectar haciendo `telnet ispl 1433` desde el equipo en la computadora donde te da el problema?

Comment: SQLServer en windows no siempre corre en el puerto 1433 a menos que lo configure, aca una guia de como verificar o configurar el puerto https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-2017